# How to remove an element automatically with javascript setinterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a chat system and am currently trying to delete messages real time. I made a function which runs every 2 seconds which checks which message has been deleted by the user on the other end. Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
message_deletion();
},2000);
function message_deletion() {
$.ajax({
url: 'functions.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {
deleteMessages:1
},
success: function(data) {
var serialize = $.parseJSON(data);
if(serialize.success=='true') {
var message = serialize.message;
$('.message-'+message+').remove();
}
}
});
}
```

Here is the html code for messages:

```
<div class="message message-193298">
<p class="message_text">Hello!</p>
</div>
<div class="message message-193698">
<p class="message_text">Hello!</p>
</div>
```

The problem, which I guess, is that the remove function needs some sort of user interaction before executing (eg: click, alert, prompt) to work properly. Because this is a chat app and everything has to work in real time, I find it no good idea to alert the user every time a message gets deleted.
What methods do you know that might actually work? I would love to know! 
And thanks in advance!

Comment: kindly post html part also.

Comment: I have added the html code but i don't think it will be of any help... Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer something like this? There are more jsibs out there.

Comment: Could you please explain me what it does and how to use it?